# Image White Line

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I'm using the following code to draw small image on a big image, but it has white lines,

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(256, 256);
Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1);
g1.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(-10, -10, 300, 300));
g1.Flush();

graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;

graphic.DrawImage(bitmap1, new RectangleF(0f, 313.5f, 256, 256));
graphic.DrawImage(bitmap1, new RectangleF(0f, 569.5f, 256, 256));

bitmap.Save("1.png");
Process.Start("1.png");
```

could someone told me why this happen?

the tile.png is an image in 256X256 with red color filled.

Comment: Maybe you could attach input/output images to explain the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```